# Generalize a query that involves multiple instances of three tables SQL

Tags: sql, join, statistics

I am doing a formula to make some statistics in SQL, but I do not know how to improve a query I am working on...

I made a [sqlfiddle so you can understand me better](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d2ff6/9)

So I have 3 tables and I need to solve  a formula varying the indexes, i,j...

```
i j
---
1 1
1 2
1 3
2 1
2 2
2 3
3 1
3 2
3 3
```

and then do some sqrt and pow. I want the result in a table but I do not know how to generalize all those long queries into one...

Comment: What is the expected result columns, to get them in one table you can union results in one table.

Comment: But is there a way to make a single query that does that instead of giving each time the parameters in the Where Clause?

Comment: If you remove where clause, how would you know to what your each row is related too. You can just remove where clause and it will give banch of number, but then you need to put your where predicates into the select statement so you have idea what is being returned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to just need a couple of `CROSS JOIN`s:

```
SELECT  ((N.n*M1.m)-(S1.s*S2.s)) / 
               (SQRT((N.n*M2.m)-(pow(S1.s,2))) * SQRT((N.n*M3.m)-(pow(S2.s,2))))
FROM N
CROSS JOIN sums as S1
CROSS JOIN sums as S2
JOIN mults as M1
     ON M1.i = S1.i
     AND M1.j = S2.i
JOIN mults as M2
     ON M2.i = S1.i
     AND M2.j = S1.i
JOIN mults as M3
     ON M3.i = S2.i
     AND M3.j = S2.i;
```

(I've modified the [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d2ff6/15) to include this.  Thanks for providing one!).

However, your overall design is a little suspicious to me; what exactly are you attempting to accomplish?

Comment: In fact these are statistics that involve variance and averages, the formula is to compute the correlation matrix of a table

Comment: Why are you using cross join for the sums table, and why join in the mults table?, the cross join does the cartesian product....

Comment: Yes, because you're going through every combination of the values in `sums`, crossed with each other (at least you were in the example you gave).  In other words, you naturally had a Cartesian product to begin with...